# How to mimic roll-up summary in formula field

Tags: formula-field, roll-up-summary, sum

I have a custom object called jobs which are related to the master object accounts.  Within the jobs object, I have a revenue field and an invoice_date field.  On the accounts page layout, I want to display the total revenue for each related job per month of invoice for the current year and the previous year.  I want the months/years to be dynamic so I, nor my predecessor, don't have to change them every year.  I am currently doing this with the roll-up summaries, but, as I mentioned, I have to change them every year.  I have established a lookup relationship within accounts with jobs, as a master-detail relationship doesn't seem to be enough, but cannot seem to get any kind of data from jobs.  In addition, there doesn't seem to be a SUM method in formula fields.

Is there any way to sum all data from a specified field (revenue) filtered by another specified field (invoice_date) in a related object (jobs) within a formula field on an object (accounts)?

Ideally, the formula might look like this, except this doesn't work:

```
if(jobs__c.invoice_date >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1) AND jobs__c.invoice_date <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,1,1), SUM(jobs__c.revenue), 0)
```

Comment: Formula fields cannot do rollup functionality.  You need to look at tools like Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries or Rollup Helper.

Answer (score 0):

First I am not sure this can ever be achieved via Formula. Second the logic which you have written wont work because :

- You said Account and Jobs have lookup relationship, and you want to roll up `Jobs` details to account, which means Account will have List, so a formula field on Account can never access the list of `Jobs` related to it.

So its best to write a trigger on `insert`, `update`, `delete` and `undelete` on `Job` object and then get calculate accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to achieve your goal, but as noted by others, you cannot use a formula field.

One option, would be to use [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary (DLRS)](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) (or a competitor package) to build the values for it.

Another solution would be to build a scheduled flow that populates the field(s) as needed.

If those two cannot work in your project then I would fall back to a Trigger or Scheduled Job to do the updates.

I generally default to DLRS on most projects, but it's a bit overkill for just one or two fields – for those a flow is likely to work fine in many cases. I try to avoid triggers when I can to keep the overall solution low-code and to make automations of that nature as easy to discover and maintain as possible for future admins (including the version of yourself 6 months from now who might have forgotten the details of what today's you does).